# Nodejs hello world

Tags: node.js

Hi guys I was hoping for a little help , My overall goal is to make an web scraper running from an server. But I figured I would have to learn how to walk before trying to run ...

So I have simplified my problem to this:

**How to get response in browser window for simple hello world app?**

This is what I have done

- Created an server at digital ocean.
- setup the server.
- Setup Putty and fileZilla

So far all of this work. But how can I get this little code to work:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, '178.62.253.206');
console.log('Server running at http://178.62.253.206:3000/');
```

When I run this from the PuTTY terminal I get this response in the console window:

```
- Server running at http://178.62.253.206:3000/
```

But when I navigate to this in chrome browser I get this error:

```
Failed to connect to 178.62.253.206 port 3000: Connection refused
```

What Im I doing wrong ? 
Any help at all would be much appreciated

Frederik

Comment: is the server port open for external requests?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. And I Suspect it is not open , but Im afraid I would not know how to fix this

Comment: I'm not into DO, but check e.g. [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server). I'd expect only port 22 (SSH) to be allowed.

Comment: I tried to change the port from 3000 to 22 , but resulted in errors

Comment: it would, 22 is a reserved port. try changing it to 80 or 8080, if those dont work, you'll have to figure out how to open 3000

Comment: Hi thanks for all your replies , I tried on port 8080 but also refused connection.. Should be something simple im missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only accepting connections from 178.62.253.206. Change this:

```
}).listen(3000, '178.62.253.206');
```

To this:

```
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: This sounded logical, and I was very exited to try this right now. I just made changes as you suggested, but still the connection gets refused , grrrr...

Comment: After running my application directly from digitalocean console I was able to get this working I also Changed the app location from root to var. Im not sure why I was not able to get this working when launching it from PuTTY